# MS Azure: routing to VM's IP based on source IP

Tags: routing, azure, virtual-network

I want to have simple yet specific setup created in MS Azure and I would like to know if it is actually possible. 
In my setup I need one Windows VM, which would have two network interfaces, both of which would be connected to a loadbalancer and the loadbalancer would connect the VM to internet with public IP. All the traffic from internet would go to the loadbalancer, which would then route it to one of my VM's network interfaces, based on source subnet: say, 15.0.0.0/8 would go to VM_IP1 and everything else would go to VM_IP2. 
I tried playing with free subscription but it seems I need to pay for custom routes and advanced scripts as well as for contacting official technical support. Can someone please advice, whether MS Azure supports such kind of routing and if so, how it should be set? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, we can’t use Load Balancer in this way, because in Azure Load Balancer, we can’t specify a network adapter in the backend pools (just support VM).
[image]
I create a VM with 2 NICs, and Azure Load Balancer just can find the primary NIC:
[image]
As a workaround, maybe you can create a VM (vm1) work as a router, two VMs in the same VNet, then add router on VM1, in this way, we can route 15.0.0.0/8 to VM2's NIC1, and everything else to vm2's NIC2.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.